Why are we interested in derived category?
It's been said in Weibel's book that ''The derived category $D(A)$ of an abelian category is the algebraic analogue of the homotopy category of topological spaces.'' But in this view shouldn't we just work in the homotopy category?  I think it is because there is corresponding between the quasi-isomorphisms in the category of chain complexes and the weak-homotopy equivalence in the category of topological spaces and we want to consider topological spaces up to weak-equivalence (like in the case of CW-complexes).
I guess that there is a theorem tells us that the singular chain complexes of two spaces (e.g. two CW-complexes) are quasi-isomorphic if and only if the two spaces are weak-equivalent. Is it right?

In homotopy theory / homotopical algebra / homological algebra there are always two notions of equivalences one might want to consider: homotopy equivalences and weak homotopy equivalences. The idea is that while the former notion is more natural, the second notion is (supposed to be) computable. More explicitly, to give a homotopy equivalence one has to describe a map in the other direction as well as homotopies, while a weak homotopy equivalence can be detected merely by considering the action of the given map on homotopy / homology groups.
So naturally people want to work with the second notion but are really interested in the first notion. Luckily, in good cases both notions coincide. In the topological case this is Whitehead's theorem, but this can be generalized vastly to the world of model categories, with chain complexes being an application.
Since we want to work with weak homotopy equivalences, we want to treat them as isomorphisms, hence we localize at them. In the topological case this yields the homotopy category of spaces $\mathsf{hoTop} := \mathsf{Top}[\text{whe}^{-1}]$, in the algebraic case it is the derived category $D(\mathcal{A}) := \operatorname{Ch}(\mathcal{A})[\text{qiso}^{-1}]$. Note that "homotopy category" is a bit of a misnomer and should rather be "weak homotopy category". This is however not much of a problem, since we prefer to work with nice spaces like CW-complexes anyway and $\mathsf{CW}[\text{he}^{-1}] \subseteq \mathsf{Top}[\text{whe}^{-1}]$ is a full subcategory by Whitehead's theorem.
Weibel's analogy can be made even more concrete: Using the Dold-Kan correspondence, one can find certain chain complexes representing a purely algebraic version of an interval and spheres. Using them to define homotopies and homotopy groups in the algebraic world, one recovers the notion of homotopy of chain complex and homology groups, thus quasiisomorphisms are literally weak homotopy equivalences! (This is at least true for all categories of modules, I am not 100% sure about the case of an arbitrary abelian category though)
Regarding your last remark, homotopy groups and singular homology are related, but (un-)fortunately not identical. A map, which is an equivalence on singular chains, need not be a weak homotopy equivalence.
